# Was the “Superman” show that was shown in Cuba in “Godfather II” a real show?

Tags: the-godfather-2

In The *Godfather II*, when Fredo leads the group of people to a club in La Habana, a show is presented where a man with a cape appears in the scene with a couple of women (if I recall correctly).

Does anyone knows if this show is for real or just something made up for the movie?

Comment: Oh yes, I saw the show. Started with "Hello, I'm Superman," then the robe was dropped, two young women joined him, and he showed that his equipment worked well.

Comment: I have to mention that this question was important with regards to Fredo sexual preference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Cuban "entertainer" known as "Superman" was a real individual who appeared in various night clubs and casinos from the late 40s until Castro came to power. Superman, for lack of a better euphemism, was a "live sex performer." He was an incredibly well endowed man, incredibly. Superman was included in that scene in "Godfather II" to show how hedonistic Havana was before Castro came to power.

You can read more about Superman of Cuba in [this 2006 Forbes article](http://www.forbes.com/2006/08/16/james-brady-on-media-cx_jb_0817fidel.html).

Comment: Delightful insigth in old Cuba

Comment: SUPERMAN WAS REAL! I was an Oiler on the Motor Vessel Hambro out of Tampa in the late 50's. The First Asst. took me ashore and we went to a Nite Club where he appeared. IT was real and LARGE.